# Which program should a batch script with extension .bat be associated with in XP sp2?

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

For some reason or other my .bat files are associated with notepad and will therefore not run.  Looking for answers, I have only found solutions for systems other that XP.  Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

- Start `regedit.exe`
- Make a backup of the registry.

---

- For **Windows 7** you should check the following:

  - delete the `UserChoice` under the following key:
    `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat`
  - Check the `Default` under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat`. It should say `batfile`.
  - If it does goto `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command`. It should say `"%1" %*`

---

- For **Windows XP** you should check the following:

  - delete the whole key
    `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bat`
  - Check the `Default` under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat`. It should say `batfile`.
  - If it does goto `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command`. It should say `"%1" %*`

Comment: Thanks for replying Rik. I didn't have the key you mentioned so I didn't have to delete it.  The other key got inserted correctly but .bat files still get opened in notepad. What does "batfile"=hex(0): do? I couldn't see what trace it left.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting my Windows-versions mixed up. What does the `Default` say in your key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat` ?? It should say `batfile`.

Comment: Yes,it does say batfile and it has a subkey [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

Comment: I edited my answer. What does `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command` say?

Comment: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command does not exist on my machine. It stops at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell with subkeys edit and print.

Comment: That's why it defaults to "Edit". You need to add the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command` with a Default value-string of `"%1" %*`. Look at the subkey for `cmdfile` and then `shell\open\command`. It should be the same for the `batfile`.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you very much.  I'm curious: which program actually runs a .bat file?

Comment: .bat files are run by cmd.exe and in older versions by command.com. (The command line interpreter)